# Supply a name to anonymous and call later in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have an int[] array = {34,65,3,65,3,2,68,8,4,2}. I want to divide this array into group of 5 and find average of each subgroup.

Comment: what does the rest of the code look like?

Comment: what about giving g.Avg() a name before the from line so var Avrg = g.Avg(); from xyz in new[] { Avrg } select xyz;

Comment: It is not clear what you want to do. Please explain further.

Comment: If it doesn't compile, that suggests there's a compiler error involved - so please include that. You also haven't mentioned what `g` is, or what you're trying to assign this query to. Basically, provide more context. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: @learningdb: You haven't updated it very much. You can't start a query expression with a "group by" clause for example. Please give us a *complete* code sample. You still haven't provided the compile-time error, either.

Comment: Ok can you tell me how to do this: I have an int[] array = {34,65,3,65,3,2,68,8,4,2}. I want to divide this array into group of 5 and find average of each subgroup and print it on console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This syntax declares (implicitly) an array of the type returned by `Avg()` method:

```
new [] { Avrg = g.Avg() }  // if g.Avg() returns int, it will be int[]
```

if you want to declare an array of anonymous types, you must do:

```
new[] { new { Avrg = g.Avg() } }
```

**EDIT:**

according to your edit, this code splits the array in groups of 5 elements and computes the average of them:

```
int[] array = { 34, 65, 3, 65, 3, 2, 68, 8, 4, 2 };

var avgGroups = from x in Enumerable.Range(0, array.Length)
                group x by (x / 5) into g
                select new { Avrg = g.Average(x => array[x]) };
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to give it a name; the object you are creating is of type

```
 IEnumerable<typeof(g.Avg)>
```

so you can enumerate through that object to get the value of g.Avg().

Answer (score 0):

Probably you want to store type in array. For this you need to have like this

```
    var v = from xyz in new [] { new {Avg =  g.Avg()} }
                select xyz;
```

Rather use this way,

```
    var v = from xyz in new [] {   g.Avg() }
                select new {Avg = xyz};
```